# What does $W_{1}$ and $(W_{1},W_{2})$ mean under the context of Brownian motion $W_{t}$?

Tags: statistics, brownian-motion

As part of some practice questions for a course I'm taking, I was given the definition of a Brownian motion $W_{t}$ as 
a unique continous-time stochastic process satisfying:

- $W_{0}=0$
- The function $t \rightarrow W_{t}$ is almost surely everywhere continous.
- The increments $W_{t_{1}} - W_{s_{1}}W_{t_{2}}-W_{s_{2}}$ are independent when $0 \leq s_{1} < t_{1} \leq s_{2}<t_{2}$
- The increment $W_{t} - W_{s}$ has a $N(0, t-s)$ distribution for $0 \leq s < t$.

This seems to make sense and I did some further research into Brownian motions, however then I was asked what the distribution of $W_{1}$ and $(W_{1},W_{2})$ would be.

I don't really know what this means, as I don't know how to express either as any more than some function that is almost everywhere continuous.. it feels like my given definition isn't exactly enough to go off of...

Comment: $W_1 = W_0 + (W_1-W_0) = W_1 - W_0$ by property 1. By property 4, this has a distribution of $N(0,1-0) = N(0,1)$.

Comment: @Brenton Ohh, I see, you rewrite it in terms of increments, so simple. So for the second part $(W_{1},W_{2})$ I imagine I'd find the distribution of $(W_{1}, W_{2}-W_{1})$ and apply a linear transformation?

Comment: @gem Yes, exactly..